# Intersection of 3D lines

Tags: analytic-geometry

How to find intersection point of lines $p... \frac{x + 1}{0} = \frac{y - 2}{-1} = \frac{z}{1}$ and $q... \frac{x - 1}{-1} = \frac{y + 6}{3} = \frac{z + 6}{4}$?

Comment: (1) What have you tried? (2) What's that division by 0 supposed to mean?

Comment: I don't even know what that means. It's just a notation trick I guess. So, $p$ has always x-coordinate $-1$.

Comment: Have you tried solving this system of equations for $x$, $y$, and $z$? Those are intersection points (if they exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\frac{x + 1}{0} = \frac{y - 2}{-1} = \frac{z}{1}=t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $x=-1, y=2-t, z=t$. So, the parametric form of the first line is $c_1(t)=(-1,2-t,t),\ t\in\mathbb{R}$. If we do the same for the second line, we get it's parametric form $c_2(t)=(1-t, 3t-6,4t-6),\ t\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus,
$$c_1(t)=c_2(t) \iff t=2. $$ Consequently, the intersection point is $A(-1,0,2)$.

Comment: You should probably not use $t$ for both parameters